# C# Desktop Application with CEF browser embedded NOT RUNNING on Client's PC, but runs on development PC's

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, google-chrome-devtools, desktop-application, chromium-embedded

I have developed a C# Desktop Application application on VS2013 that has CEF(Chrome Embedded Framework) in it. The Application is developed on .NetFramework 4.5.2 with Target Platform set as x64 (It has to be x64 otherwise CEF doesnt work)

The App runs on the developer PC but when i install it (using a setup) on Clients PC and simply run it by clicking the installed .exe , the mouse pointer loads for a few seconds and then nothing happens. It doesn't appear in task Manager either. I have tested it by installing another C# Desktop app developed in the same environment and configuration but without CEF , and it is working Fine in all the client's PC's.. Is there any problem with the CEF?

Following are the Specs of Developers PC and the Clients PC.

Developers PC :  [Application Running]
Windows 10
OS = x64 bit
Visual Studio 2013 with .NETFramework 4.5.2
Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package
CEF .dll files included and placed in Debug Folder

Another PC 2 :     [Application Running]
Windows 7
OS = x64 bit
Visual Studio 2013 with .NETFramework 4.5.2
Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package
CEF .dll files included and placed in Debug Folder

Clients PC 1       [Application NOT Running]
Windows 8.1 
OS = x64 bit
Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package
CEF .dll files included and placed in Debug Folder

Clients PC 2     [Application NOT Running]
Windows 8.1 
OS = x64 bit
Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package
CEF .dll files included and placed in Debug Folder

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's missing something. Might have wrong version of .NET or it can't find the CEF dlls. Why put them in a debug folder on a client machine? Is the exe in a debug folder?

Comment: it has the same version of .NET i.e 4.5.2. Plus if its a version, the other application with the same Framework wouldnot work either. 
I have tested it both ways ,  1) By installing the exe  and 2) Copying the debug folder from my machine to clients machine .. same probblem wither way

Comment: you  need all the CEF (sharp?) dlls in the same folder as the exe.

Comment: Yes they are in the same folder. As the application ran on another PC of mine without any Problem, there aint an issue with the placement of the CEF Files..

Comment: depending on CEF version (45+), you might need VS 2013 redist, not 2012.

Comment: Mabye  , let me try that  .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool built into windows called sxstrace.exe that can help determine what is missing.

1) Run something like:

```
sxstrace trace -logfile:mylog
```

2) Try to launch the application

3) stop the trace (press any key in cmd window)

4) parse the logfile like:

```
sxstrace parse -logfile:mylog -outfile:mylog.txt
```

5) view output file for errors

EDIT: In your case, very likely missing some CEF files. From their documentation:

> The following files, in addition to the usual .NET project files,
>   should be present in the bin directory. They should live side-by-side
>   in the same directory as the CefSharp.Wpf.Example.exe file, except for
>   en-US.pak which is in a locales subdirectory:
>
> cef.pak devtools_resources.pak icudt.dat libcef.dll /locales/en-US.pak

Comment: Yes. They are in the same directory as the .exe file.. And if that was the case , the application would have also not worked on other PC's ... I would try the sxstrace tool.. 
Any other possible reason you think can effect? The fact that VisualStudio2013 is not installed on Clients PC? because all other PCs that have VS installed are running it and all of the Clients PC that dont have VS installed are not...

Comment: SO why this is accepted but not mentioned what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not releasing a Debug version of your application. That might explain the dependency on MS VS being installed. In my C++ experience debug builds sometimes require some DLLs that can only be found in a Visual Studio installation.

Another debugging idea: download a Sample Application and place just the executable (cefclient.exe) into your project installation. It is important to fetch the version that corresponds to your CEF version. Try to run the simple app. If it works, then the required binary dependencies and assets are there and the problem is somewhere else.